# Associating a Part to a different table

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I want to attach a Part to a content item, let's say Priority. The part is PriorityPart. I want the PriorityPart to take a string field Priority from a different table. Let's say PropertyPartRecord.

I was able to get the data from the propertyPartRecord table but I can't sent the data into it.

Here's my classes.

PriorityPartDriver:

```
protected override DriverResult Editor(PriorityPart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper)
{
    var model = new EditPriorityViewModel();
    updater.TryUpdateModel(model, Prefix, null, null);
    return ContentShape("Parts_Priority_Edit",
           () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(TemplateName: TemplateName, Model: model, Prefix: Prefix));
}
```

EditPriorityViewModel:

```
public class EditPriorityViewModel
{
    public string Priority { get; set; }   
}
```

PriorityPart:

```
public class PriorityPart : ContentPart<PropertyPartRecord>
{
    public string CurrentPriority { get { return Record.Priority; } }
}
```

PropertyPartRecord:

```
public class PropertyPartRecord:ContentPartRecord
{
    public PropertyPartRecord()
    {
        Priority = "1";
    }

    public virtual String Priority { get; set; }
}
```

Editor View Priority:

```
@model ePageo.TUI.MediaManager.ViewModels.EditPriorityViewModel
<fieldset>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Priority, T("Priority"))
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Priority, new { @class = "text large" })
    @*@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Priorities.SelectedValue,@Model.Priorities)*@
    @*@Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.OrderTemplates, new SelectList(Model.OrderTemplates, "OrderTemplateId", "OrderTemplateName", 1), "Please select an order template")*@
    <span class="hint">@T("Please provide a numeric priority for the media item. 1 being highest priority and 100 being the lowest. Default is 1.")</span>
</fieldset>
```

I just couldn't add data into the PropertyPartRecord table. It does add the default value of 1 but then it never updates.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm doing it this way because I'd later add more fields to the PropertyPartRecord table which may or may not have its own parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add this piece of code in the Driver:

```
part.CurrentPriority = model.Priority;
```

Since the part was not associated to the viewModel.

```
updater.TryUpdateModel(model, Prefix, null, null);
part.CurrentPriority = model.Priority;
return ContentShape("Parts_Priority_Edit",
       () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(TemplateName: TemplateName, Model: model, Prefix: Prefix));
```

Now its working.